# Can I create a feed out of all of the Stack Exchange sites which I want to simultaneously follow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, quora

I would actually like to be active on many sites on SE, but Id like to just have one feed, one place where I can go to check on things that I follow or am interested in. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10):

Yes! You can use the **[Stack Exchange filter system](https://stackexchange.com/filters/)** to filter out questions from specific sites (and from specific tags if you want!)

[image]

Then, you can get the feed (the link is located at the bottom of the page).

[image: Feed]

Comment: just curious to know how inbox will looks when you have feed with php tag .... thousand of mail in single day :P

Comment: @NullPonyPointer: I'm betting he'll follow some of the lower volume sites? :P

Comment: Im really new here. Does it not make sense to follow large volume sites because they will overload the feed? I guess Im just very used to the feed model--its just way more comfortable for me that to jump between site to site. Am I right?

Comment: also, is it possible to create filters for certain tags of a stack exchange website? for example, i would like to have CSS in my feed but I would not like to have the entire stack overflow website on my feed.

Comment: @user11920: Stack overflow gets about 13 questions a minute, do the math. And yes, it's possible to filter by tag (refer to the link and my image for more information, I trust that you find it :P)